# How to subscribe to the jobs mailing list?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to subscribe to the jobs mailing list?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260336/how-to-subscribe-to-the-jobs-mailing-list?/) by [NataliaDiazRodr](https://answers.ros.org/users/29872/nataliadiazrodr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-04-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-04-26**:
Can you clarify which mailing list you are referring to exactly?

**Comment by [NataliaDiazRodr](https://answers.ros.org/users/29872/nataliadiazrodr/) on 2017-04-28**:
This one https://discourse.ros.org/c/jobs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> This one https://discourse.ros.org/c/jobs

That is not really a mailing list in the traditional sense, but a Discourse *category*. I believe you should get notified of all posts to `discourse.ros.org` by default, but if you just want to receive postings to certain categories, go to *Preferences*  (the little cog icon, top-right in the drop-down menu after you've logged in and clicked on your avatar image), then scroll down to *Categories* and configure it for the categories that you'd like to watch / be notified about.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1